# get keys of an array starting from 1 and counting

Tags: php

Is there a way to get sum of the keys of an array starting from 1 and counting until the end of the array (10 in the example below).
So if all checkboxes are checked the result should be 55 (1+2+3...+10). I've assigned keys starting from 1 but it didn't work.
That's what I have so far.
Here is the array (values do not matter now, they will be processed later):

```
<?php  
$rank1_1[1] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="1" />h';
$rank1_1[2] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="7" />w';
$rank1_1[3] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="20" />n';
$rank1_1[4] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="44" />m';
$rank1_1[5] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="81" />l';
$rank1_1[6] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="133" />k';
$rank1_1[7] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="203" />p';
$rank1_1[8] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="292" />b';
$rank1_1[9] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="403" />s';
$rank1_1[10] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="537" />b';
 ?>
```

The process:

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($rank1_1); $i++)
echo $rank1_1[$i], '<br />';  
$keys = array_keys($checked_1);
foreach($keys as $keys_s) {
$keys_sum +=  $keys_s;
  } 
?>
```

And the result:

```
<?php 
 echo '<br />$keys_sum  = '. $keys_sum; // $keys_sum = 45
 print_r ($keys_sum); // Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 
 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 6 [7] => 7 [8] => 8 [9] => 9 )
?>
```

Moreover if I check 8-th, 9-th, and 10-th boxes the result is:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3]
```

How can I make it work as expected? Please help.

Comment: There's a ton of repetition in your code there. Why not generate those programmatically?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just count if there are 10 checkboxes?

Comment: If your array has 10 elements (count($arr)=10) starting at $arr[0] then the last one will be $arr[9]. Your code is accessing $rank1_1[count($rank_1_1))] which is beyond the end of the array. Your use of digits in variable names makes me think you've not really understood how to use arrays. Using the index from one array to resolve data held in another array is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Is every key value pair in the array assumed to be checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that every key value pair in the $rank1_1 array is considered "checked", then your answer is pretty simple:

```
$rank1_1[1] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="1" />h';
$rank1_1[2] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="7" />w';
$rank1_1[3] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="20" />n';
$rank1_1[4] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="44" />m';
$rank1_1[5] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="81" />l';
$rank1_1[6] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="133" />k';
$rank1_1[7] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="203" />p';
$rank1_1[8] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="292" />b';
$rank1_1[9] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="403" />s';
$rank1_1[10] = '<input type = "checkbox"  name = "v_1[]" value="537" />b';

echo array_sum( array_keys( $rank1_1 ) ); // 55

echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';
```

But if you need to make sure the values are checked as in $checked_1, then I can only assume your values are 1, 7, 20, 44, etc.

```
$checked_1 = array( 1, 7, 20, 44 );
```

In that case, you would need to match like this:

```
$i = 1;
foreach( $rank1_1 as $key => $value )
{
    foreach( $checked_1 as $x )
    {
        if( strpos( $value, 'value="' . $x . '"') !== FALSE )
        {
            $found[] = $i;
            $i++;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if( isset( $found ) )
    echo array_sum( $found ); // 10
```

With all that, if any $checked_1 element is just adding to your count, and if it always starts at 1, then you might just do this:

```
$total = 0;
for( $x = 1; $x <= count( $checked_1 ); $x++ )
{
    $total += $x;
}
```

If none of this helps you out, I think you need to give us an example of what $checked_1 looks like, and what your expectations look like.

UPDATE -----------------

In regards to your recent comment, do you mean like this:

```
foreach( $rank1_1 as $key => $value )
{
    foreach( $checked_1 as $x )
    {
        if( strpos( $value, 'value="' . $x . '"') !== FALSE )
        {
            $found[] = $x;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if( isset( $found ) )
    echo array_sum( $found );
```

UPDATE 2 --------------------

Sum of the keys:

```
foreach( $rank1_1 as $key => $value )
{
    foreach( $checked_1 as $x )
    {
        if( strpos( $value, 'value="' . $x . '"') !== FALSE )
        {
            $found[] = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if( isset( $found ) )
    echo array_sum( $found );
```

Comment: Brian, thanks a lot. Sorry, probably I was not very clear. Checkboxes will be randomly checked by user, and each checkbox must have its own weight according to their numbers (someday it may become a knowledge test ;). All your examples work and give the sum but they don't consider the weight of checkboxes. $checked_1 is an array of checked checkboxes. Do you have an idea how to make it?

Comment: Check the last part of my revised answer, and let me know if that is what you mean.

Comment: No, this one counts the sum of values, not the sum of keys. I need the sum of values too but I already have it (a bit different way). Maybe I can somehow stop using keys -- divide values in two, and then explode them by separator. Could this be implemented here?
Let me try to explain what I want once again. I have data (array?) with couples of related values. One part of the array (in my example above -- keys) is an arithmetic progression and the other one is logarithmic (in my example -- values).
I want to be able to count the sum of each progression in any combination. Any ideas?

Comment: Answer now has sum of the keys at the bottom.

Comment: The last one works great. Thanks a lot, Brian Gottier!

Comment: Glad it worked Ken. If this is your accepted answer, please mark it as accepted. Thank you.